# Unity3d: How to create a sliding(by touch) list?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need create a sliding(by touch) list in my mobile game. It may be something like in the following picture:
[image]

By touching and sliding downward, the rest of the list would be shown.

Comment: Well, take a look at [ScrollRect](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html)

Comment: I can only find Scrollbar in my Unity3d(5.1.2) but no ScrollRect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [ScrollRect](http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.html) component to the GameObject you want to make scrollable. Here's [Unity official tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcU8yzv_xEw) about how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUun2xW6FJ4) how to make a basic sliding menu.

For list element, probably you will need more than a button. If this is the case, you can create an empty object name "listItem" and design a list item with texts, buttons, images etc. After that turn this object into a prefab.Then you can add element layout to the listItem instead of button as seen in the video. Here there is an example screenshot:

[image]